# How to show ngx-loading animation only to router-outlet?

Tags: angular, loading, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

I have a layout component with the following template,

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<section class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

router-outlet: this shows the various screens depending upon the selection done on app-sidebar.
But I want to show loading screen before the screen get rendered fully in the section.

I am using ngx-loading https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading .

Please help me How can I do it?
How to have event emitter from the screens when a user clicks on the sidebar.

My Layout Component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedServiceService } from '../../services/sharedService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-layout',
    templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = false;
    constructor( private sharedService: SharedServiceService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I have One component called home from side bar.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear what you're asking but I think you can handle it like that :

HTML :

```
<ngx-loading [show]="!resolved"></ngx-loading>
<router-outlet (activate)='resolved=true'></router-outlet>
```

TS :

```
public resolved = false;
```

This way you can any component you want while route resolving isn't finished

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use out of the `Router.events` :

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } 
 from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this._router.events.subscribe(evt => {
      if(evt instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loading = true;
      } else if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
}
...
```

Then simply use the `loading` variable in your template :

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading"></ngx-loading>
```